# Unable to transfer bitcoin from Multibit - need Satoshi

Tags: multibit

When I am trying to transfer ALL my bitcoins from MultiBit wallet - It's giving error saying:

"The send transaction could not be created

The error was "Insufficient money, missing 49967 satoshis"

I am trying to send my bitcoins and I am entering the exact number of bitcoins which it is showing in my wallet for doing transaction. Can someone please help.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to include a transaction fee as well, so you can't send the entire balance in your wallet. Decrease the amount you are trying to send by the amount it suggests and try again.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @MeshCollider . But i am transferring bitcoins and not satoshi. What should I try? How do I know the max amount to get entire balance out of multibit?

Comment: I got it. I entered only the amount that was showing up in big letters. Transaction fee is in settings. Thanks for the help.

Comment: To clarify for future reference, a satoshi is just 0.00000001 BTC, it's just a small unit of bitcoin, 10^8 satoshi in one bitcoin)

Comment: Hey @user531069 if this answered your question then it'd be great if you could accept it :)